# How to set elasticsearch index sorted and change field names

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to ask that I want to fetch data from elasticsearch with elasticsearch rest client, but ı want that documents sorted via a field, and before that I want to change some field names in elasticsearch documents.

I've searched on the internet, but these websites were saying calling settings api but for this I should have mapping set and mapping can be set only once.

I'm so confused for this. Can someone give a basic sample for this? Thanks a lot

Comment: When I trie to change index mappings I got this error => resource_already_exists_exception

Comment: changing the field names for the document will require a re index operation. I'm guessing you are trying to `PUT your_index {mapping: {properties....}}`, and that is creating an error. As far as the sorting, you can use [sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html) to get the order of results you want